# Installation uninstallation shows error but works why?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I get the following message when I remove or install a program but it installs or uninstalls correctly. please help me resolve it.

```
Package operation failed
The installation or removal of a software package failed  

Details

installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 190360 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mahjongg ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0 ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae (3.2.0-24.39) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-24-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of overlayfs
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.2.0-24-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.2.0-24-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-24-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
 linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-pae:
 linux-generic-pae depends on linux-image-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.24.26); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
 linux-image-generic-pae
 linux-generic-pae
Error in function: 
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae (3.2.0-24.39) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-24-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of overlayfs
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.2.0-24-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.2.0-24-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-24-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
 linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-24-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-pae:
```

Comment: Please put output in code blocks by using the "<$>" button in the editor for readability. I edited for you here, but something to keep in mind. What command did you run that produced this output? It is helpful if you include that too.

Comment: Don't know why the problem occurs but it is caused it seems by a kernel upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

That's a false alarm, it just means that the startup process could not be changed. It's just a pointless process that linux goes through after doing something like that. The process is only there to make sure that the program removal scripts haven't changed the boot. The program you're removing (Mahjongg) is perfectly safe to uninstall so you haven't got anything to worry about.

Comment: This is a real error: the OP has unconfigured packages -- and the log clearly states that.